# Android SQL Query multiple WHERE args

Tags: android, android-sqlite, where-in

For some reason my sql.query is failing because of the way it is formatted.  I have no idea why.  It does not crash nor does it throw an error. It simply does not return a value.  I am using two WHERE arguments in the query.  I see in the Log.d that both arguments are successfully passed to the method.

```
public static String fetchLightTableD(String flightRowId, String filenamePrefix){

    String[] lightcolumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LUXVALUE, KEY_TRANSMITTED };
    Log.d("CSV", "SQL fetchLightTableD, revceived tid - " + filenamePrefix + " " + flightRowId);
    Cursor lightcursor = myDatabase.query(LIGHT_TABLE, lightcolumns, KEY_TID + "=" + filenamePrefix + " AND " + KEY_ROWID + "=" + flightRowId, null, null, null, null);
    String lightTableResults = "";

    int iRowId = lightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iTid = lightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TID);
    int iName = lightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iLux = lightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LUXVALUE);
    int iTrans = lightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TRANSMITTED);

    for (lightcursor.moveToFirst(); !lightcursor.isAfterLast(); lightcursor
            .moveToNext()) {
        lightTableResults = lightTableResults
                + lightcursor.getString(iRowId) + ","
                + lightcursor.getString(iTid) + ","
                + lightcursor.getString(iName) + ","
                + lightcursor.getString(iLux) + ","
                + lightcursor.getString(iTrans) + "\n";


    }

    return lightTableResults;

}
```

It should be filtering the table for the row that matches both the rowid and the filenameprefix. I have also tested removing one or the other WHERE args to make sure values actually exist.  Of course they do, so there is something wrong with my AND.  Can anyone see where it is incorrect?

The equivalent should be as so:

```
SELECT lightcolumns 
FROM LIGHT_TABLE 
WHERE KEY_TID=rowid AND KEY_TID=filenamePrefix;
```

Comment: If `filenamePrefix` is a **string**, as I strongly suspect, you have to surround its value by **'** (single quote)

Comment: well both are technically strings.  If I remove the WHERE for the TID then it functions fine.  Surrounding it with single quotes did not work.

Comment: read about String[] selectionArgs parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your query like this

```
 Cursor lightcursor = myDatabase.query(LIGHT_TABLE,lightcolumns,
            KEY_TID "=?"+ " AND " + KEY_ROWID +"=?",
            new String[] { filenamePrefix , flightRowId},null, null, null);
```

instead of

```
Cursor lightcursor = myDatabase.query(LIGHT_TABLE, lightcolumns, KEY_TID + "=" + filenamePrefix + " AND " + KEY_ROWID + "=" + flightRowId, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Good job.  I will study why this argument format worked and not the original.  Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String Query = "SELECT " + lightcolumns + " FROM "+ LIGHT_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TID + " = "+ rowid + " AND " + KEY_TID + " = " +filenamePrefix ; 

Cursor lightcursor = myDatabase.rawquery(Query ,null);
```